# New avatar feature?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that a small number of user's avatars are now rendered with a drop shadow that tends to<sup>1</sup> indicate that if they are moused over the user's profile will pop-up.

[image: screengrab of the "feature"]

Is this a new feature that is being trialled before wider roll-out?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiYzc.png) I say "tend to" because it doesn't appear to work for all of them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what it indicates, or should. They've been enabled on the main meta for a few days now, and just went live network-wide a couple hours ago. You can read more about them and the specific requirements in [How does the User card work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-work), but in short if you have enough reputation and your "about me" is long enough, you'll get a user card popup

I just realized you have a drop shadow, but no card (I don't think your "about me" is long enough). That seems like a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), but I'll ask around to find out for sure

Comment: thanks, that was what I suspected, but when I saw that old timers like you and Gilles didn't have them, my curiosity was piqued...

Comment: @jason Sadly we don't have our "about me" sections filled in. I should really it to nab [Autobiographer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/badges/9/autobiographer)

Comment: Jasons "About Me" was too short to show so the indicator was a bug - he's right on the boundary so make it a tad bit longer @Jason

Comment: Thanks @Geoff - I've been a tad more expansive...